# holomorphic injective function

Tags: complex-analysis

> > Prove: Let $z_o \in G\;$. There exists a holomoprhic injective function for every $n \in \mathbb N$ $\;f_n:G\rightarrow D_1(0)$ such that $f_n(z_0)=1-\frac{1}{n}$

I don't know how to find such a map. Can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: Is $G$ bounded?

Comment: You need to tell us what you're assuming about $G$. This is obviously false if $G=\Bbb C$, for example...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $G$ is bounded, there is nothing fancy going on. Consider maps of the form $a + bz.$

Comment: And if $G$ is unbounded but not dense in $\mathbb C$, hten a suitable Möbius transformation will convert it to a bounded set, and then this answer will apply.